# Why is this word displayed as uppercase in web page?

Tags: html, css, uppercase

Check out this web page: http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/clubs/profile.overview.html/tottenham

Why is word "Lilywhites" displayed as uppercase in web page?

Comment: It is? (Cannot find it.)

Comment: +1: This is strange. The source does show it being proper-cased, and there is no computed style for text-transform to upper case.

Comment: @Nikodemus: It's in the blue on the right hand side under "Nickname".

Comment: NICKNAME

Spurs / Lilywhites ? <-- Not upcase here. So, maybe something done by javascript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it is simply the font:

```
font-family: 'PremierLeagueRegular';
```

within:

```
.clubheader ul.stats p 
{
    font-family: 'PremierLeagueRegular','Lucida Grande','Lucida Sans Unicode';
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 4px 0;
}
```

If you were to remove the `'PrimierLeagueRegular'` font from the `font-family` property, you would notice that it changes away from being an uppercase font.

Answer (score 0):

in

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/etc/designs/premierleague/clubs.css" type="text/css">
```

find

```
.clubheader ul.stats { 
    display:block; float:right;
    font-family: 'PremierLeagueRegular','Lucida Grande','Lucida Sans Unicode'; 
    color:#fff;font-size:18px;font-weight:normal;line-height:18px; 
    width:165px;vertical-align:top;position:absolute;top:0;right:0;
    }
```

PremierLeagueRegular font is the reason